# android java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)

Tags: java, android, file, android-external-storage

I got an error in console crashes & anrs. This error is showing sometimes and I couldn't find where the problem is.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
```

The function code to save picture is:

```
    public static String sharePhoto(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Folder");
    boolean success = true;
    String file_path = null;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
            file_path = folder + "/Img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".jpg";
        }
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file_path);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // Do something else on failure
    }
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(file_path);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    return file_path;
}
```

Comment: Do you have needed permissions?

Comment: Yes, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Show all of the code. Show the entire exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should check this again: File f = new File(file_path); --> The file_path here is null

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/MyFolder");
```

Thing is that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `File`. You need to get absolute path of that file and concatenate with `"/Pictures/MyFolder"`.

Comment: Ok, I will try it for some days and see the results. Thanks.